# How to do code optimization by knowing that how my android app is consuming lots of memory, CPU and network?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am new to Android App development. My question here is, how to understand why my Android application is consuming more memory usage with CPU and network?

See the below image, where I am checking with Android Profiler and it says that Memory usage is 32 MB.

How to know where memory leakages are happening and consuming more memory? How to optimize the code by avoiding memory size consumptions?

The important thing is to know about Memory leakages and out of memory errors. But, I am not getting any idea what is showing here with the help of Android Profiler. I have done some research based on this but for code optimization, how to monitor using Android Profiler and rewrite the code?

Even, using Android Lint tool also, it is showing only about the code warnings than showing leakages but my Android app is getting crashed and hanged or paused in a run-time often.

[image: I am checking with Android Profiler and it says that Memory usage is 32 MB]

Comment: first try to check if you context or activity reference is leaking somewhere or not. You can use android lint tool to test it.

Comment: Yes, using Android Lint tool also... It is showing only about the code warnings than showing leakages but my Android app is getting crashed and hanged or paused often.

Comment: You can use Firebase Crash Reporting to monitor the possible issues: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ . Or if you are interested in the techniques that most often cause memory leaks, this article was useful for me: https://android.jlelse.eu/9-ways-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-android-b6d81648e35e